# adding two numbers in prompt, verify both inputs are numbers, alert if wrong format

Tags: javascript

I need to ask the user in a prompt for two numbers, add them together then give an answer, it should also verify both inputs are number and if not prompt them with wrong data. help?

```
function addTwoNumbers() {
    let num1 = parseInt(prompt("Provide the first number:"));   
    let num2 = parseint(prompt("Provide the second number:"));    
    if(isNaN(num1) || isNaN(num2)) {        
        alert("The final score is: ", (num1+num2));   
    }
    else {
        alert("Wrong data");
    }
}
```

Comment: Just invert the if condition. When showing the final score, the current logic is trying to add the numbers when either of the numbers is not a number.

Comment: Case matters in JavaScript. `parseInt !== parseint`

Comment: Javascript is case sensitive, meaning `parseint` is not the same as `parseInt`,

Comment: @MetroSmurf What is wrong with the downvotes? Do you assume that this question is going to be helpful to future visitors? If it were, then surely there would be a duplicate? Voting on SO is a content rating system. They first and foremost determine how useful a question/answer is.

Answer (score 1):

Your if clause is wrong. If we look at it:

```
if(isNaN(num1) || isNaN(num2))...
```

What you are doing here is checking if num1 OR num2 are not a number then it should add it. What you really want to do here is check if BOTH are numbers. So you have two possibilities here:

```
if(isNaN(num1) || isNaN(num2)) {
   alert("Wrong data");
}
else {
  alert("The final score is: ", (num1+num2)); 
}
```

This checks is either of the num variables are not a number. If one or the other is not a number, then an error should be shown.

```
if(!isNaN(num1) && !isNaN(num2)) {
   alert("The final score is: ", (num1+num2)); 
}
else {
  alert("Wrong data");
}
```

In this one, we are checking if, for both numbers, isNaN returns false, meaning that they are both a number.

Answer (score 1):

In your second statement:

```
let num2 = parseInt(prompt("Provide the second number:"));
```

`parseint` ≠ `parseInt`

Also, keep in mind that you are currently showing the user the final score if one of both number is NOT a number.

```
if(!isNaN(num1) && !isNaN(num2)) {   
       alert("The final score is: ", (num1+num2));   
}
```

This should do the job.